# How to use internally authorize Google API for OAuth in my facebook app

Tags: django, web-applications, oauth, google-api, gdata-api

I am building a Facebook application using Django where I am using Blogger API. So, all I want is to just read the data from a public blog (my blog).

I tried to read the documentation and found that we have 3 types of authentication mechanisms (ClientLogin, OAuth, AuthSub Proxy). As I can't directly put login credentials in the application (insecure), I have only one option to use. i.e., OAuth.

The tricky part of my project is, the "users"(facebook users) should be able to access my data without providing any authorization information to Google. However, in the eyes of Google - OAuth, as I am pulling data from blog to display to public, I am considered as "user" who needs to authorize the application when ever someone opens the app on facebook, which is completely absurd...

So, there might be two ways to do this:

1. I should be able to pull data from blog without any authorization of user..

How can I do it? If not

1. I should be able authorize my application internally for OAuth so that facebook users can access data without providing any information to google.

How can I do this?? If possible, is this a secure way?

- I am quite new to OAuth, Google API.. so, please suggest the best and secure way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `Google API Access Token` pulling public data.. or `OAuth Service account`.

Either of these would do your job.